# Can I have a function within a sub?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Public Function WorkDayDiff(ByRef StartDate As Range) As Integer

        Dim Counter As Integer
        For Counter = 1 To DateDiff("d", StartDate.Value, Now())
            If Weekday(CDate(StartDate.Value + Counter)) > 1 And Weekday(CDate(StartDate.Value + Counter)) < 7 Then
            WorkDayDiff = WorkDayDiff + 1
        Next Counter
End Function
```

I need to use the value `WorkDayDiff` of this function in a Sub. Is there a way I can put this function in the Sub where the value is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a read of this:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/differen.htm

In the mean time, you can call it from a sub, but not put it in a sub, if I understand you correctly you want this.

```
sub MainSub()
    dim myDate as range
    set myDate = sheets("Sheet1").range("A1")
    WorkDayDiff myDate
end sub
Public Function WorkDayDiff(ByRef StartDate As Range) As Integer

        Dim Counter As Integer
        For Counter = 1 To DateDiff("d", StartDate.Value, Now())
            If Weekday(CDate(StartDate.Value + Counter)) > 1 And Weekday(CDate(StartDate.Value + Counter)) < 7 Then
            WorkDayDiff = WorkDayDiff + 1
        Next Counter
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, giving it a go now :)

Comment: using the format you suggested I get a mismatch error 13 for the lines where I use the WorkDayDiff value, is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Oups, didn't notice that the function was expecting a range.  This has now been updated.  Have a look at the answer now, it expects a date value in sheet1 range A1